# Html popup window from code behind file

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, popup

This could be a simple but I havent found any easy solution.

On clicking button in asp.net web page on button click event html is generated from xml and xsl. This html is stored as string variable. For example lets say

```
dim htmlString as string = "<div>This is my popup</div>"
```

From the above html string how can I dynamically create html popup window in vb.net. I can create popup window on front end by using javascript but havent found any solution to create it through code behind file in vb.net

Edit:

This does not work in IE, only works in firefox:

```
Dim popupScript As String = _
   "<script language='javascript'> myPopup() </script>" 
Dim mystring = "<html><body><div style=""color:black"">Name: Jame's</div></body></html>" 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "PopupScript", String.Format(popupScript))
```

Comment: I assume that this is ASP.NET, isn't it? How about: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", url))`

Comment: Thanks Tim that is what I needed, I figured this out after posting the question. Just wondering if there is any different way of doing it without using the javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create a popup-window with javascript, so you need to register that script from codebehind:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", url))
```

Maybe i've misunderstood your requirement. You want not only to open a client-side popup(`window.open`) from codebehind but also create that window on the fly without url?

Maybe this helps(untested):

```
Dim popupHtml = "<html><body><div style=""color:black"">Name: Jame's</div></body></html>"
Dim openPopupScript = "NewPopup=window.open("", 'newWindow', 'height=250, width=250');" & _
                      "NewPopup.document.open();" & _
                       String.Format("NewPopup.document.write('{0}');", popupHtml) & _
                      "NewPopup.document.close();"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), _
                      "newWindow", _
                      openPopupScript)
```

Comment: How can i pass vb.net strig whcih contains html to the javascript function as a parameter.      <script type='text/javascript'>

        function myPopup(test) {           
            var popupwindow = window.open("myWebForm.aspx", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");            
            popupwindow.document.write(test);
            popupwindow.focus();
        }
    </script>

Comment: on code debhind file     Dim popupScript As String = "<script language='javascript'> myPopup() </script>"

        mystring = "<html><body><div style=""color:black"">Name: Jame's</div></body></html>"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "PopupScript", String.Format(popupScript))
 doe not work on IE only works on firefox

Comment: @Jemsworld: You should have edited your question, add this and ask me in comment. I will do so.

Comment: @Jemsworld: added an approach to create the  popup without an URL, but it's totally untested.